# Uncaught TypeError: form.submit is not a function in form validate() function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, validation

when form submit and if validation triger true than its display error on form.submit();

```
 submitHandler: function(form) {
                    debug: true,
                    success1.show();
                    error1.hide();
                    form.submit();
                }
```

[image]

```
form html like this 
     <form method="post" id="clientordeR_create12" onsubmit="enableItemtax();"
                              action="<?php echo base_url('Clientorder/save'); ?>">

 all input eliments here

     <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn green"
                                                   value="Save &amp; Print" formtarget="_blank" id="spSlip"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML <form> in your question too.

Comment: html form are too long

Comment: You might need to manual type check if the requested form is actual a form. Something like this `if (typeof(form) == <SOME_TYPE>) {form.submit()}`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You most probably have a button or input in your form with **`id="submit"`** and/or **`name="submit"`** like this:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="someName" />
  <input type="email" name="someEmail" />
  <!-- Other form elements -->
  <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This will change `form.submit()` to a field reference rather than a method call. You can verify this by console logging `form.submit()` which will most probably return the `<button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>` element instead.

To fix this, you need to either remove the **`id="submit"`** and/or **`name="submit"`** attributes or change them to something else like this:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="someName" />
  <input type="email" name="someEmail" />
  <!-- Other form elements -->
  <button type="submit" name="submitBtn" id="submitBtn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Holy cow, all these years, and I didn't realize this was a thing. And sure enough, I was copy/pasting some code, and this was exactly the dang reason form.submit() was failing for me... for hours. Thank you so much for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

simply change input type submit or button type submit name = submit to othername and id name also same as name

```
  <input type="submit" name="submit"  id= "save" class="btn green"> 
    change to like this and error solved in my case 
    <input type="submit" name="save"  id= "save" class="btn green">
```